# Prime Divisors In Recursion

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I need to print all the prime divisors of a given number n.

I have tried to write some code and found that the stoping condition is if n is prime or that we got to 2.

What I have hard time is to find a way to still send an element to the function, without "loosing" the given number n, it was easy if I needed the prime factorisation, in this case I would send to the function n divided by the founded prime divisor to get the input smaller

Edit: I understood that it is equivalent to finding the prime factorization

my code:

```
function y=PrimeR(n)
if isprime(n)==1
    y=n

else
for i=floor(sqrt(n)):-1:2
       if mod(n,i)==0
           y=[i,PrimeR(n./i)]
       end
end
end
end
```

Comment: You say _I need to print all the prime divisors_ and _it was easy if I needed the prime factorisation_. Isn't it the same? Your question is unclear. Also, show your code and point out what specific problem you have

Comment: @LuisMendo correct, it is the same, edited

Comment: Look up the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, should help you write much more efficient code

Comment: You can literally just do `factor( n )` or, for unique prime factors, `unique( factor( n ) )`... Is the aim of this question to fix non-working code (i.e. this is an exercise and you have to write the algorithm), or just get the result (i.e. you can use built-ins)?